# Share User folder along different versions of Ubuntu running Gnome classic desktop

Tags: home-directory, shared-folders, user-profile

Whenever I did installed several versions of Ubuntu in order to test and choose, I would like to know how can I share the same /home Folder or the same /home/user Folder. All these installations have the same user name with the same password. Specially I would like to share the Firefox History & Bookmarks, also than the Download folder. Anywhere I run the Gnome classic desktop. All the installed distributions are in the same disk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really don't want to do this. Newer versions of applications may make incompatible changes to the configuration, which the older versions can't handle. As a result, when you do run the newer versions of Ubuntu, you may then have issues running the older versions, due to such incompatible changes.

For Firefox history/bookmarks, you probably should use Firefox Sync perhaps; though I don't know that it supports syncing history. For the Downloads folder, you could have it be on external storage, and simply mount that partition/drive under all the versions of Ubuntu, or you could use Ubuntu One to sync the folder as well.

Comment: I agree with you, but I was not sure, so my real problem is that I would like to update Firefox bookmarks and tabs from another Firefox running inside a different distro.

Comment: Sorry. Updated the answer to address the bookmarks/downloads parts as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you are dual booting multiple *buntu flavors (or any Linux distro really), I would highly recommend a separate /home partition. It removes configuration time for programs that are common to all your different distro installs. Firefox will use the config from your /home right off the bat instead of the default. Gnome, as well, will use the existing /home config files. At that point you only need to fill in the holes, installing the additional programs you prefer.

There is a more important reason than ease of configuration for a separate /home. Every time you install a new distro on the hard drive, you will be removing /home from that process. This helps to ensure that your other personal items (pics, docs, music etc.) will not be corrupted or over-written during the install. If you already installed without a separate /home [this will guide you](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving) to remedy that. A more complete explanation of partitioning can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition).

Comment: I finally used Firefox Sync, between 3 different profiles at two different distros, it supports history also. I had to remove repeated items.

Comment: That's cool, glad you found a solution.